# Only run r.neighbors if cell meets criteria

Tags: raster, grass-gis, raster-calculator, conditional

This is my first time using GRASS to work with Rasters, so please excuse my lack of knowledge on the subject.

I want to run the GRASS r.neighbors function on cells that meet a specific criteria, and ignore running the function that do not meet that criteria.  In addition, I still want to use the values that do not meet the criteria in the neighborhood calculations.

For example, I have a raster with integer values, and I want cells with a value of 1, 2, and 3 to run the r.neighbors function, but not values of 4, and 5.  When the function gets to cells with values of 1, 2, or 3, r.neighbors should run, and include all cells within the neighborhood (even ones with values 4, and 5).  When cells of 4, and 5 are encountered, I simply want to do nothing and move to the next cell.

Here is a very similar [Knowledge Base article](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/21261) from Esri that does this, but with NoData cells.  I need to do it using GRASS.

Looking at the [documentation for r.neighbors](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.neighbors.html), I do not see a clear way to approach this.  I do not believe I can simply loop through the raster cells and run the r.neighbors function since the output is a new raster each time it run.

If that is the case, then perhaps I can reverse engineer the r.neighbors function within a conditional?  I just have no idea how r.neighbors determines it's neighborhood.

1. How does r.neighbors walk through the raster collecting cell values?

   - If so, then how does it do this?
   - Ultimately, this is what I want to know the most!
2. Would I be better off trying to do this outside of GRASS?

   - If so, what are your recommendations?

Right now, I am just stuck on where to go.

---

I am most interested in learning how (systematically) r.neighbors collects the neighborhood values.  What functions, methods, etc. does GRASS use to *read* specific cell values within a) a certain number of cells **OR** b) a specific distance in *n* direction of a given cell?  I believe knowing this will help me the most going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Does r.neighbors walk through the raster collecting cell values?

> The neighborhood operators determine a new value for each cell as a function
>   of the values in its neighboring cells. All cells in a raster map, except for
>   the cells at the map boundaries, become the center cell of a neighborhood as
>   the neighborhood window moves from cell to cell throughout the map ([Open Source GIS: A GRASS GIS Approach.](http://www.grassbook.org/))

Look also [GRASS Tutorial:r.neighbors](http://www.ing.unitn.it/~grass/docs/tutorial_62_en/htdocs/comandi/r.neighbors.htm)

2) Would I be better off trying to do this outside of GRASS?

You can use [R](http://www.r-project.org/) with GRASS as in [Terrain Classification Ideas: Coupling GRASS and R](http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/drupal/node/221) or [R](http://www.r-project.org/) without GRASS

Comment: Thank you for your reply and suggestion. I realized I should have been more clear in what I want (see edit comment above). I am more interested in exactly how the window "finds" the appropriate cells.  I understand the theory of it, but if I need to reverse engineer the r.neighbors function, I need to know (systematically) what r.neighbors does to collect the cell values within it's neighborhood window.  I will look into R and see how promising it is.  Thanks!

Comment: You can examine the C sources [r.neighbors Directory Reference](http://fossies.org/dox/grass-6.4.4/dir_d9edafed37e91e392de98376458931fb.html)

Comment: See also "r.neighbors treating NULL values" here: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2014-October/071011.html